# how to hide "reset password" button in dotnetnuke (login module)

Tags: authentication, passwords, dotnetnuke

I use DotNetNuke 7 and I want to hide login "password reset" button from the form .

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it with this CSS, either embedded into you portal.css file, or into the skin.css

```
.dnnLoginActions {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked great.Remeber clear history of browser. I was even able to apply it on other places. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the functionality my making an edit in the web.config file.  That will apply to the entire DNN installation, not just a single portal.